# Ubuntu based OS won't boot

Tags: boot, kubuntu, xubuntu, lubuntu, mint

I have tried installing Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, and Linux Mint and after the install process is done they never boot up. The screen just turns black ans stays like that. Bodhi Linux works and Debian does too but I want to run Xubuntu or Kubuntu on my computer. I have a netbook with 2Gbs of RAM, 160Gbs of HDD and an Intel Atom 1.33GHz processor.

Comment: Have you been able to get any of these OSs working from the live CD before you installed them??

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is your video chipset.  You do not say what version of *buntu.  Try: booting to the login screen.  Don't log in.  Press the 'Ubuntu' button at the side of the login screen (on Ubuntu 12.04) and change setting to Unity 2D.

If your setup is different please ask again with full information especially video card/controller/chipset.